# WUBI Windows installer won't launch on Windows 98

Tags: windows, wubi, usb-drive, cd-drive

Have an old PIII 1GHz machine that I'd like to try to use as a homework writing / editing / printing machine for the kids and maybe share the printer on the home net, but it doesn't look like I'm going to be able to get Ubuntu installed. Please tell me if I'm missing a trick here:

1. No CD-ROM in the machine.
2. BIOS doesn't have an option to boot from a USB drive
3. Windows '98 currently installed, but when I try to run WUBI, it just exits. No error message, just start, stop. Nothing left running in the task manager.

I disabled the (very old) AV program, no difference.

Comment: If your computer is that old to run Windows 98, how do you expect to install Ubuntu? I think you install Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu, because it's a lightweight operating system that uses Ubuntu with the LXDE desktop environment.

Until Lubuntu 11.10, was required only a minimum of 128 MB of RAM to run and 256 MB of RAM to install with the graphic installer. The recommended minimum RAM to run a live CD session is 384 MB. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu

You can believe on me, as I'm Lubuntu user.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on this quote from Ubuntu Wiki, Windows 98 has not been thoroughly tested, knowing that I would recommend to do the normal installation of it, by creating a partition to install it.

> **Which Operating Systems are supported?**
>
> Windows 7, Vista, XP, and 2000 are known to work with Wubi. Windows 98 should also work, but has not been thoroughly tested. Windows ME is not supported. Linux is supported through Lubi.

From: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide